# Unknown encoding and encoding converting using php

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm use third party authorization service for my project. This service return my name like this: u0438u0432u0430u043d, but my name is - иван. How can I convert encoded value (u0438u0432u0430u043d) to иван in php?
Thanks!

Comment: Those are mangled unicode sequences. They should look like `\u0438\u0432etc...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got Unicode hex sequences there - try adapting something like this...

```
function decodeToUTF8($s) {
    //turn udddd into an HTML entity
    $s=preg_replace('/u(....)/', '&#x$1;', $s);
    //turn entities into UTF-8
    return html_entity_decode($s, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is right solution:

```
protected static function decodeToUTF8($s) {
        //turn udddd into an HTML entity
        $s=preg_replace('/u([A-Fa-f0-9]{4})/', '&#x$1;', $s);
        //turn entities into UTF-8
        return html_entity_decode($s, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    }
```